# Standard way to semantically tag data in a PDF document?

Tags: pdf, rdf

I know that one can embed RDFa in XHTML documents. Is there any standard accepted way to do this for PDF? (By "standard", I mean in a way that major search engines recognize.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Standard way to semantically tag data in a PDF document?*

Yes, there is. It is called "Marked Content". You can read about it in Chapter 10 - Document Interchange, Part 10.5 - Marked Content of the [PDF Reference Sixth Edition](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html)

Comment: How do I know that google or other search engines will pick it up the same way they pick up RDFa tags from XHTML?

Comment: That's the way of defining meta-data tags for PDF, whether Google and al. use them or not, I cannot say, but they probably do.

Answer (score 2):

See the **XMP** specification: ( http://www.adobe.com/products/xmp/ and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform ). Some scientific publishers fill the metadata of their PDFs (eg: www.nature.com)

Comment: The problem with this is that the PDF specification doesn't provide a way to mark individual words in a page: I couldn't, for example, provide semantic data for a single name or technical term that is buried in a paragraph of text.